# How to set Vertical Scrollbar that display current position in blackberry?

Tags: java, blackberry, scrollbar

I want this type of scrollbar in my app

[image]

I tried this :

```
 new VerticalFieldManager(HORIZONTAL_SCROLL|HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR|VERTICAL_SCROLL|VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR|VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_MASK);
```

But it not worked

Currently it display this , i don't want this :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [getVirtualHeight()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#getVirtualHeight%28%29), [getVerticalScroll()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#getVerticalScroll%28%29) from the class [net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html) and [getVisibleHeight()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/ScrollView.html#getVisibleHeight%28%29) from [net.rim.device.api.ui.ScrollView](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/ScrollView.html)
it is possible to implement custom scroll bar on Manager.

Check this BlackBerry Knowledge Base Article, [Implementing a standard style scrollbar on a Blackberry device](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implementing-a-standard-style-scrollbar-on-a-Blackberry-device/ta-p/504416).

I have used that class, `VerticalScrollManager` and it works well. Followings are example code snippet and generated output.

Code:

```
int maxWidth = 200;
int maxHeight = 100;

VerticalScrollManager vsm = new VerticalScrollManager(maxWidth, maxHeight);

vsm.add(new ButtonField("ButtonField 1"));
vsm.add(new ButtonField("ButtonField 2"));
vsm.add(new ButtonField("ButtonField 3"));
vsm.add(new ButtonField("ButtonField 4"));
vsm.add(new ButtonField("ButtonField 5"));
```

Output:

[image: Output of the above code]

Another helpful link, [Scrollbar Component in Blackberry](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Scrollbar-Component-in-Blackberry/td-p/492301).

Answer (score 0):

From the javadoc, it seems that you should use only:

```
VERTICAL_SCROLL
HORIZONTAL_SCROLL
```

Using bitwise operations with values that are not meant to be used in that case can result in unpredictable results.

Answer (score 0):

you can override the `paint` method in `VerticalFieldManager` and paint that scroll bar from scratch, there is no other default scroll bars than the one you mentioned.

Comment: But how to trace current user Position

Comment: with the method `getVerticalScroll`